# Submit Feedback to SQL Database with C#/HTML

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am attempting to run a C# function when a button is pressed that gets a rating (1-7) and puts it into a database along with a text input. The feedback portion:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="AnswersPlaceholder" runat="server" Visible="false">

<asp:Literal ID="AnswerLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<br />
<br />
<div class="FeedbackTitle">How accurate do you find this result?</div>

<center><p><input class="FeedbackChoice" type="checkbox" value="1"  name="feedback"  id="F1">Way off!</p></center>
<center><p><input class="FeedbackChoice" type="checkbox" runat="server" value="2"  name="feedback"  id="F2">Mostly inaccurate</p></center>
<center><p><input class="FeedbackChoice" type="checkbox" runat="server" value="3"  name="feedback"  id="F3">Somewhat accurate</p></center>
<center><p><input type="text" style="width:40%; border: solid,thick; border-color:blue" name="Note" runat="server" class="FeedbackNote" /></p></center>
<button class="ContinueButton" runat="server" onclick="SubmitFeedback_click">Continue</button>
```

and the function it calls:

```
protected void SubmitFeedback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FeedbackNoteString = "";
    string FeedbackButtonString =  "";
    int UseUserID = 0;
    int Feedback = 0;
    try
    {

        UserInfo _currentUser = UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo();
        UseUserID = _currentUser.UserID;
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Errors[0].Message);
    }

    finally
    {


    OleDbConnection bConnection = new OleDbConnection("Driver={SQL Server};Provider=SQLOLEDB........(credentials hidden)");
    OleDbCommand DoesFeedbackExistCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM ss_QuizFeedback WHERE UserId = " + UseUserID.ToString(), bConnection);
    OleDbDataReader DoesFeedbackExistReader = DoesFeedbackExistCommand.ExecuteReader(); SqlConnection SSSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand FeedbackNoteCommand = SSSqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    SqlCommand FeedbackButtonCommand = SSSqlConnection.CreateCommand();

    bConnection.Open();

    while (DoesFeedbackExistReader.Read())
    {
        Feedback++;         
    }

    if (Feedback == 0)
    {
            FeedbackNoteString = "INSERT INTO ss_SoulGoalsQuizFeedback (UserId,SoulGoalsNote) VALUES ("
            + UseUserID.ToString() + ","
            + Request.Form["Note"] + ")";

            FeedbackButtonString = "INSERT INTO ss_SoulGoalsFeedback (UserId,Rating) VALUES ("
            + UseUserID.ToString() + ","
            + Request.Form["feedback"].ToString() + ")";
    }

    else if (Feedback != 0)
    {
        FeedbackNoteString = "UPDATE ss_SoulGoalsQuizFeedback (UserId,SoulGoalsNote) VALUES ("
        + UseUserID.ToString() + ","
        + Request.Form["Note"] + ")";
    }   

    FeedbackNoteCommand.CommandText = FeedbackNoteString;
    FeedbackNoteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    FeedbackButtonCommand.CommandText = FeedbackButtonString;
    FeedbackButtonCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SSSqlConnection.Close();
    bConnection.Close();
}    
}
```

When the button is pressed, the page refreshes but does not put them into the database.

Comment: Try to output your `INSERT` statement to see what you are calling and run it on your database. Also your `UPDATE` query is not correct.

Comment: Not relevant comment..  but avoid _SQLInjections_.

Comment: This is the weirdest code ever.  How can you be using `Console.WriteLine` in web site code behind?  Why does so much happen in your `finally` block (should only contain cleanup code really)?  The code structuring is probably masking the exception that is causing this to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is probably generating invalid SQL.  For example

```
FeedbackNoteString = "INSERT INTO ss_SoulGoalsQuizFeedback (UserId,SoulGoalsNote) VALUES ("
+ UseUserID.ToString() + ","
+ Request.Form["Note"] + ")";
```

should be

```
FeedbackNoteString = "INSERT INTO ss_SoulGoalsQuizFeedback (UserId,SoulGoalsNote) VALUES ('"
+ UseUserID.ToString() + "','"
+ Request.Form["Note"] + "')";
```

or even better

```
FeedbackNoteString = String.Format("INSERT INTO ss_SoulGoalsQuizFeedback (UserId,SoulGoalsNote) VALUES ('{0}','{1}'), UseUserID.ToString(), Request.Form["Note"]);
```

(Notice I have added single quotes around the two strings you are concatenating with the SQL.)

Incidentally, your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.  You might want to consider performing these database operations with a stored procedure instead.